# Is there a limit on directory removal with Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console

Is there a limit on directory removal with Google Webmaster Tools?

I have a bunch of directories that I need to remove. I've already edited my *robots.txt* to disallow these. Some of the pages are being 301ed as a catch all, but I really need Google to just blow them away.

Comment: If you need them "blown away" use 302 redirects, 301 means temporary moved page, while 302 defines permanently moved page.

Answer (score 1):

You have already done the best thing it seems. As long as links exist, Google will want to follow the link, however, blocking them in *robots.txt* is the best and fastest way to remove something from the SERPs. The Remove URL tool in Google Webmaster Tools is slow and relatively useless compared to robots.txt. But please know this will take a while. You cannot hurry Google up- you will only make them mad. You do not want a mad Google do you?? Be patient. It will work out okay. Not the end of the world.

Comment: I saw "submission to crawl" has a 500 page and a 10 directory limit.  Just wanted t o make sure removal of directory does not have a limit.

Comment: @runners3431 There is a limit, but I cannot tell you what that is, I just do not know. I avoid using this option as much as I can. When you submit a URL removal in Webmaster Tools, it will tell you how many requests remain- at least it did the last time I looked almost 2-3 years ago. Honestly, the robots.txt is the fastest way. I ended up resorting to using the robots.txt file the last time because the Remove URL request did not seem to have an effect. This is because if there is a link or the page resolves, Google will continue to list the URL if it is not blocked using the robots.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing, just note down the list of directories that you want not to be crawled by search spiders. One way is block those directories in *robots.txt*. In fact, you can use Google Webmaster Tools to remove such directories.

Comment: so i updated my robots.txt file to disallow those directories, then i went to google webmaster tools, and submitted a directory removal.  however my custom search engine still shows those directorys.  The status in Webmaster Tools is "REMOVED.", there is even an option to "REINCLUDE".   I am going to assume maybe these directions are out of date now?  http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/03/url-removal-explained-part-i-urls.html      even if i remove the directories, will those 301 redirect pages remain?